# zsh, modularity,multiple .zsh files and oh-my-zsh

Tags: debian, shell, zsh

I use/enjoy zsh and have used oh-my-zsh in couple. While it's all nice and cool, I do get irritated that I have to constantly update the oh-my-zsh script every 15 days/month .

Now I have put zsh as a prompt on another machine. Now the good thing about my oh-my-zsh is that instead of putting everything in .zshrc which when you install .zsh does, it does it in multiple directories with .zsh extension.

While I do not want to go that whole hog, is there a way I can put multiple *.zsh files under say ~/.zsh/ and strive to have a similar working environment.

Can this work or am I missing something ?

Running zsh on debian 64-bit.

Update - There are only two files which can be in my zsh installation -

```
think-debian% pwd
/home/shirish

think-debian% ls .z
.zcompdump  .zshrc
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: could you put that in a way I could understand instead of just giving a script. What is the script trying to achieve and what I should be doing. Please put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can set your Zsh dotfiles directory with the `ZDOTDIR` environment variable; just add it to your `~/.zshenv`:

```
ZDOTDIR="${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME/.zsh}"
```

Then, source any files in that directory that are named `*.zsh` from your `~/.zsh/zshrc`:

```
if [[ -d "$ZDOTDIR" ]]; then
  for file in "$ZDOTDIR"/*.zsh; do
    source "$file"
  done
fi
```

For bonus points, uninstall Oh-My-Zsh and enjoy Zsh as it was intended, a powerful and flexible alternative to Bash, not a bloated ratmangle...

Comment: umm... there is no `~/.zshenv` file/directory in my zsh installation. Should I create it ?

Comment: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html

Comment: I read the link you shared. While it tells the purpose it doesn't tell how to use it.

Comment: Such is life...

Comment: have updated my question with what files are viewable. This installation is a clean zsh installation, no oh-my-zsh at all in this installation.

Comment: What is the point of setting `ZDOTDIR`? Wouldn't the for loop work anyway even without it?